# 2 storage accounts created when i created a single vm on azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I wonder why there are two storage accounts were created when i created a Vm on azure? One consists of only blob, while another consists of all blobs, files, tables and queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder why there are two storage accounts were created when i
>   created a Vm on azure? One consists of only blob, while another
>   consists of all blobs, files, tables and queues.

One storage account should be for your VHDs using which a VM is created. This should be the storage account with only blobs and should be a `Premium` one. Other storage account (with everything) should be for the diagnostics data for your VMs.